# LinkedIn Api - Invoice Api to get any Invoice as Pdf

Tags: linkedin-api

Is there any Api for LinkedIn which allows to get any Invoice (as PDF) ? I searched through the LinkedIn Api Documentation, but could not find such an Api.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.